# how to use str replace in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

Array ( [0] => Array ( [trigger] => E [alttext] => C ) [1] => Array ( [trigger] => F [alttext] =>D ) )

```
foreach ($trigger as $tdata) {
                $tr = $tdata['trigger'];
                $ttext = $tdata['alttext'];
                $text= str_replace($tr, $ttext, 'A B E F');
           //If im echo this result then result is 
           Result = A B C F A B E D

            }
```

And:

```
   foreach ($trigger as $tdata) {
                $tr = $tdata['trigger'];
                $ttext = $tdata['alttext'];
                $text= str_replace($tr, $ttext, 'A B E F');
                      }
            //If im echo this result then result is 
          Result = A B E D
```

But I want to show `A B C D`

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are always going back to the original string to do the replacement - you need to do accumulative changes.  So here it sets `$text` with the original string and each time does the replacements in this string...

```
   $text = 'A B E F';
   foreach ($trigger as $tdata) {
       $tr = $tdata->trigger;
       $ttext = $tdata->alttext;
       $text= str_replace($tr, $ttext, $text);
    }

    echo $text;
```

The only thing you have to be careful about with this method is that if the text you replace with earlier is something you later search and replace with.  So `E` -> `F` and `F` -> `D` would be `A B D D`.

Update:

With your test data...

```
$trigger = Array ( Array ( "trigger" => "E", "alttext" => "C" ) , 
    Array ( "trigger" => "F", "alttext" =>"D" ) );
$text = 'A B E F';
foreach ($trigger as $tdata) {
    $tr = $tdata['trigger'];
    $ttext = $tdata['alttext'];
    $text= str_replace($tr, $ttext, $text);
}

echo $text;
```

Comment: Not sure how you get the result, can you show your code.

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [trigger] => E [alttext] => C ) [1] => Array ( [trigger] => F [alttext] =>D ) ) ` my data Base structure

Comment: If your base data is arrays - change the following lines to use `[]` - `$tr = $tdata['trigger'];   $ttext = $tdata['alttext'];`, output I get is `A B C D`

Comment: i did it but no result :( only last one is updated  Result = A B E D

Comment: I've added what I've tested with.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this (assuming these are similar to your database rows):

```
<?php
$rows = [
    ['E', 'C'],
    ['F', 'D']
];

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $find    = $row[0];
    $replace = $row[1];
    echo str_replace($find, $replace, 'A B E F');
}
```

Output:

```
A B C FA B E D
```

We could do this in one pass via the following two methods:

You can pass str_replace two arrays of corresponding find and replaces:

```
echo str_replace(array_column($rows, 0), array_column($rows, 1), 'A B E F');
```

Output:

```
A B C D
```

Or use strtr with an array (from => to) (`['E'=>'C', 'F'=>'D']`):

```
  echo strtr('A B E F', array_column($rows, 1, 0));
```

Output:

```
A B C D
```

You'll have to build your arrays of find and replacements, and use one of those methods that suits.  Note there is slight difference in the way str_replace and strtr substitutes.

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [trigger] => E [alttext] => C ) [1] => Array ( [trigger] => F [alttext] =>D ) )` my data Base structure